# Club several eclipse projects into one?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have several modules of a project and i have made each module as a project in **eclipse** as a seperate project..
Now i want to combine those projects in a masterproject..
Is it possible to do it?
thanking you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on project. Go to build path->Configure build path->Projects. here you can add any project (which is already in eclipse) on the build path.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can easily set things up so that one project uses other projects. Simply right click on the project in the package explorer, then click Build Path, then Configure Build Path, then add Project. Voilà!